# Add fontawesome glyph to class with css only

Tags: css, font-awesome

I am using a static HTML generator that does not let me control the structure of portions of the output. In the output I get the element

```
<div class="pubDate">publication date</div>
```

I would like a glyph to be placed `:before` this class, but can't modify the HTML tag. Can I do it with CSS only (not resorting to javascript)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I copied the CSS styling of both the `fa` and `fa-calendar` styles from [the font-awesome CSS file](http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.css) into my CSS file.